Getting Screenshot from Right Click of Mouse on Windows 11
I am using Windows 11. I try to get screenshot while mouse has right clicked. I used both Windows Key + Shift + S combination and Print Screen button on keyboard and Snipping Tool, menu that appears after right click is disappeared. Do you know how to get screenshot while mouse has right clicked?

Do you know how to get screenshot while mouse has right clicked? - I tap "PrtSc" key (i.e. print screen) ... hope that helps

As I mentioned, when I tap print screen and click mouse, the menu that appears after right click of the mouse is disappeared.

Ahh, I see, this seems to happen when right clicking the screen, not in a program, at least not in any program that I've right clicked in

Please describe specifically what happens when you tap the PrtScn key, give a step by step description. Have you configured the PrtScn to do something other than its default behavior, because it sounds as though you have, and that means that your not including this information leaves us only able to guess at what the cause. That said, there are a variety of good tools out there, some already suggested in the answers, that support capturing context menus.

Hi, here is the video record of the action: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d7cugbhn5OZ0KjueKU0ZGPCopDhh4FKD/view?usp=sharing

In Windows 11, the Snipping Tool has a button to let you set a delay for this kind of thing, like menus that disappear on button press:

Pick a delay time, click +New to start the timer, open your right-click menu, and wait for the screenshot

I am not able to do this, could you please take a video recording?

@tahasozgen you should be the one taking the recording of whatever you're trying to do, you haven't even mentioned what you're exactly trying to screenshot...

Hi, here is the video record of the action: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Nkbf574__rH7q3wn0kcTa4Qa3sU_W_di/view?usp=sharing

@tahasozgen It looks like it's working. The screen is frozen when it goes dark after the timer like in your recording. While it's frozen, you can click+drag to take a screenshot that includes the right-click menu. It looks like you are not dragging in the video, so it just un-freezes instead

I use a tool called GreenShot, which is perfect for this.
In the settings, you can define a small delay, for example 500ms (half a second).
You press PrtScrn, then quickly right-click and wait.
The mouse cursor then changes to a capture window, but you'll find that the capture will include both your popup menu and the mouse cursor as well.
After you made a selection, you can then choose what to do with it. Have it in your clipboard, edit it with the powerful build-in editor, to annotate, add arrows, draw squares, hilight, blur, etc, and from there you can copy it back into the clipboard to paste it somewhere else.
Or you can save the file to disk, upload it to image hosting sites, and more.
You can find it at https://getgreenshot.org.
Also, GreenShot can be installed from all the major app distribution platforms, such as PatchMyPC, Ninite, Chocolatey, scoop, etc...
